# A conceptual question about tf-idf using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, tf-idf

In the official documentation of pyspark, they have an example of tf-idf.

```
hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
tf.cache()
idf = IDF().fit(tf)
tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
```

I'm also ready in other sources a code similar to that. Question is: Why the name of that dataframe is tfidf? Does the result equals to tf * idf or will it stores only the idf? If so, how to calculate the tf*idf?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#tf-idf), `HashingTF` is a [`Transformer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-guide.html) which takes sets of tokens and generates term frequency vectors. TF is incorporated in this step.

```
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=20)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
```

Next - `IDF` is an [`Estimator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-guide.html) which is fit on a dataset and produces an `IDFModel`. IDF is incorporated in this step as `IDFModel` down-weights tokens that occur frequently.

```
idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
```

`idf` estimator has to be fit to produce a transformer. Hence the final steps are:

```
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
```

Comment: Hi Viseshini Reddy! Thank you for your answer, however, I still don't get it. rescaledData will store a sparse vector with some values, right? My question is, are these values the result of the idf, therefore I should somehow multiply by the featurizedData in order to obtain the tf*idf, or, are these values already the real tfidf? I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: `rescaledData` stores the TF-IDF result. The pipeline described above calculates TF first and then IDF which are then fit together using `idf.fit(featurizedData)`